# How do I remove a liquid deglosser from my cabinet doors?

Tags: cabinetry

I put a liquid deglosser on about half of our kitchen cabinet doors, and now I realized what a mistake that was, and want to remove it.

So far, the only effective means of getting it off have been a heat gun and scraper, but it's taking forever.

Is there some trick that I can use to quickly and thoroughly get rid of the deglosser residue?

Comment: I am a bit confused.  I thought deglazer was used on leather.  Are you referring to a finish stripper?

Comment: The product I used was Klean Strip "easy liquid sander deglosser" it was, presumably, going to take the finish off our cabinets to help get them ready for paint.

Comment: For future reference, the two options for refinishing are remove (back to bare wood) and prepping the existing finish for overcoating with a new finish or more of the same finish. When applying fresh finish to old finish the surface should be clean *and dull*, which is what a deglosser is for. But the same job can be done quite swiftly and effectively with fine Scotch-Brite or steel wool. Note: if the old finish is shellac or true lacquer and you're applying more of the same neither step is necessary as they will partially dissolve the old finish when applied so meld with it.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, @graphus! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thank you for letting us know about the deglosser not removing the varnish. I was wondering if it was working, due to the fact that it was still glossy after I applied the deglosser

Comment: @Gabe what occurred to make you conclude that the deglosser was a mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are now in the process of removing the old finish which is exactly what you were attempting to avoid by employing the liquid sander/deglosser..

The manufacturers of the deglosser (note it is not deglazer, a product used for leather preparation) specify to use it for preparing a previously finished surface for refinishing with no need to remove any residue - apply deglosser, let it dry, apply new finish. The deglosser is intended to make the new finish better adhere to the old finish.  It's understandable how one would be confused, given that the brand that you selected also makes a liquid paint remover/stripper.

If I were in the same situation (i.e. half way through stripping with a heat gun) I would grit my teeth and finish stripping.  True, it's going take time, but you have a chance of completing the task with a uniform surface preparation and uniform application of finish for all of the cabinets.

Comment: Well then. I was under the impression that the deglosser was going to remove the finish instead of covering it up. Lesson learned. Is there a product I can use to remove it, such as mineral spirits or some sort of paint stripper?

Comment: So that's it? No miracle liquid in a bottle that'll dissolve the dried deglosser?

Comment: Paint remover/stripper perhaps.

Comment: Brought home some of the most toxic stripping compound I could get. Will try it out in the morning.

Comment: Perfect Answer +1.

Comment: @ast paint stripper worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The deglosser keeps you from having to sand. You just apply for time specified, then prime, then paint. The deglosser removes any poly or varnish that was on prev coating - allowing new coats to stick to it. It is a real time saver. You want to pay attention to the “OPEN TIME” specified on your deglosser. This is the amount of time you have to apply yourctopcoats, once deglosser is applied.

Comment: Deglossers do not remove poly or varnish, they merely 'key' the surface. Also note that poly *is* varnish.